# Custom workflow activity for SP 2007 appears in Designer's action picker but won't add

Tags: 2007, workflow, custom-actions

This is SharePoint 2007.  I created a custom workflow activity in Visual Studio 2008 (using [this](http://moss2010.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!4299AAC7892465EB!169.entry?sa=446505706) and a few other blogs as a reference).  I deployed it properly, I think.  I can go into SharePoint Designer 2007 and see my action in the list of available actions.  But when I click it and press Add, nothing happens.

I've used samples I've found as well as simplifying the code in my activity as much as possible.  It doesn't change anything.  So I don't think it's my code there, but it's hard to say.

Comment: I would love to see an answer to this. I am having the same issue with SPD 2010

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple web front ends?  Did you do an iisreset?  I've seen similar behavior when it wasn't installed on all WFEs with a farm wide reset.

Comment: No, just one front end.  I have done iisresets.  That doesn't seem to help.

I've also changed the name of the assembly in the .actions file and am able to break it - SPD will tell me that the assembly wasn't found.  So I know it's at least seeing the assembly.  But I found it won't error if I use a class name that I know doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

*Side note: the following steps working (for me) in test enviroment.*

The steps that I follow for get custom activity working (selectable) are:

**->** Check web.config changes and integrity structure of custom activity files (.action, .cs, etc):

```
 <SafeControl Assembly="TestCWA1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7b0c1cea1fea1132" Namespace="TestCWA1" TypeName="*" Safe="True" SafeAgainstScript="False" />

 <authorizedType Assembly="TestCWA1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7b0c1cea1fea1132" Namespace="TestCWA1" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
```

[Source of the code given for this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130610/sharepoint-2010-workflow-custom-activity-not-going-into-workflow)

- [Clear SharePoint Designer cache.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/)
- In my case, I create a .actions file, but I didn't added the WSS.ACTIONS schema file. The .actions file must be also contained in a SharePoint mapped folder [as is described in this source.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13604.sharepoint-2010-create-a-workflow-activity-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx)
- Execute `iisreset` command.
- Open SharePoint Designer and create a new Workflow and select the custom activity.

In your question, you didn't mention how you created the custom activity and *(since the link of your question is broken)* it's hard to continue debugging.

I followed this same steps in production enviroment, but my custom activity doesn't working for me *(i.e selectable)*, but if anyone else have more information to add, please try expand this answer.